# Kivy (Android): ScrollView.scroll_to() doesn't show widget hidded by keyboard

Tags: python, android, kivy

when a user click on a widget on my application, the keyboard that appears can hide it if the widget is too low.
I tried `ScrollView.scroll_to()` to ask for a focus on the widget, it works but it doesn't take the keyboard in the equation.

[Before I click on "Raison Sociale".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7VKQ.jpg)

[After I click on "Raison Sociale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otvxl.jpg)

So the widget is hidded by the keyboard.
I don't know if a function like this already exist.

```
If widget.hiddedByKeyboard():
    widget.show_taking_consideration_of_the_keyboard()
```

There is also the problem of the widgets at the end of the `Screen`, if we try to show them by scrolling down, the `ScrollView` will try to go up again even if that will hide the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, this attribute will do all the job.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh the classic, the keyboard covers the widget problem. I encountered this and here's what I did to solve it:

In my KV file I had something like this:

```
<MainWindow>:

    ... [A BUNCH OF WIDGETS] ...

    ScrollView:

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height

            ... [A BUNCH OF WIDGETS] ...

            Widget:  # The important widget
                id: buffer
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: root.buffer
```

I added at the bottom of the ScrollView a blank Widget whose height was defined by a NumericProperty in the top level widget (Window - a BoxLayout).

In the Python file I had:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window  # Need to import this 

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    buffer = NumericProperty()
```

Then when I requested the keyboard, I made sure to set `buffer = Window.keyboard_height`. This adjusted the height of blank Widget to the height of the keyboard, essentially creating extra room for the keyboard. This gives the user extra scrolling room to position the keyboard.

You can combine this implementation with the `ScrollView.scroll_to()` method to create a really nice effect. Essentially pass `ScrollView.scroll_to(text_input_widget)` when the user clicks on the TextInput. This will automatically scroll the ScrollView down so that the TextInput is at the top and the keyboard is below it.

This probably isn't the cleanest implementation (I could probably do it better now), but the concept of creating a blank Widget whose size is the height of the keyboard would be the same.

Comment: That's a nice trick ! Do you know the name of the function that is triggered when the keyboard is called to add the `buffer = Window.keyboard_height` directly to it ? (if not, I'm just gonna bind it with every `TextInput` the `on_focus()` method).

Comment: I did it using the `on_focus()` method. Like I said there may be a clearer implementation. Perhaps try `buffer = NumericProperty(Window.keyboard_height)`. Alternatively, you could create a custom class - meaning that you would only type out this binding once